# PUT request being called more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, put

I'm new to Ajax/jQuery and I am doing an assignment where I must use http method `PUT` to update a django model. The code I currently have works except for **one issue**: the `PUT` request is being run multiple+1 times each time I click on a new modify button and submit the form.

Example via `console.log`:

```
(index):121 BUTTON: Pressed modify on product ID: 87
(index):133 GET: Looped through products for ID 87 and set the values in the modal accordingly
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 87
(index):121 BUTTON: Pressed modify on product ID: 88
(index):133 GET: Looped through products for ID 88 and set the values in the modal accordingly
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 87
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 88
(index):121 BUTTON: Pressed modify on product ID: 89
(index):133 GET: Looped through products for ID 89 and set the values in the modal accordingly
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 87
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 88
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 89
```

Code for ajax:

```
//        MODIFYING A PRODUCT
product_ul.on("click", ".modify", function () { // On clicking modify
    var id = $(this).parents('li').attr('id'); // Get the PK which is the ID of the <li>
    console.log("BUTTON: Pressed modify on product ID: " + id);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'get/',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, value) { // Loop through all products from the json response
                if (value.id == id) { // If PK matches product PK from response
                    $('#dataModal').modal("show"); // Show modal
                    $('#edit_name').val(value.name); // Set the values
                    $('#edit_description').val(value.description);
                    $('#edit_price').val(value.price);
                    console.log("GET: Looped through products for ID " + id + " and set the values in the modal accordingly");
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $("#modify_product_form").submit(function (event) { // On submitting the modify form
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent refresh

        var product_data = { // Get the values from the form
            name: $('#edit_name').val(),
            description: $('#edit_description').val(),
            price: $('#edit_price').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: 'modify/' + id + '/',
            data: product_data,
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", "{{ csrf_token }}");
                console.log("PUT: Received put request for ID: " + id);
            },
            success: function (product) {
                var product_html = "<li id=" + product.id + "><button class='delete btn btn-xs btn-danger'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></span></button>" +
                    " <button class='modify btn btn-xs btn-warning'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span></button> " +
                    product.name + "</li>";
                $('#' + product.id).html(product_html); // Change the html to the modified version so it updates the list
                $('#dataModal').modal("hide"); // Hide the modal
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This is how the webpage looks:

[image: modify button]

And after clicking the modify button:

[image: modal]

My only assumption so far is that the `$("#modify_product_form").submit(function (event)` is within `product_ul.on("click", ".modify", function ()` thus causing some conflict but I don't know how else I could get the `var id` without having them nested.

How I expect the `console.log` to look like:

```
(index):121 BUTTON: Pressed modify on product ID: 87
(index):133 GET: Looped through products for ID 87 and set the values in the modal accordingly
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 87
(index):121 BUTTON: Pressed modify on product ID: 88
(index):133 GET: Looped through products for ID 88 and set the values in the modal accordingly
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 88
(index):121 BUTTON: Pressed modify on product ID: 89
(index):133 GET: Looped through products for ID 89 and set the values in the modal accordingly
(index):153 PUT: Received put request for ID: 89
```

Please let me know if I should provide any other code and I apologise if your eyes hurt from seeing my amateur coding!

140256257

Comment: you could add html then we would figure it out how to get this `id`

Comment: @hodiecode I figured this out from the answer below. I declared an empty variable before `product_ul.on("click", ".modify", function ()` like so: `var selected_product = "";` and assigned it within the method: `selected_product = $(this).parents('li').attr('id');` then simply referenced it in `$("#modify_product_form").submit(function (event)` like so: `url: 'modify/' + selected_product + '/',`

Comment: great but this selected_product will be Global Variable... and thats not good practice. Better to create an object like `my_shared_object = {}` and then `my_shared_object.selected_product=""` so to avoid using Global Variables. Read more about why not to use global variables https://gist.github.com/hallettj/64478

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding a submit event handler for your form (`// On submitting the modify form`) *inside* your click handler for the product (`// On clicking modify`). That means that every time you click on a product `ul`, a new copy of the submit event handler gets added. When the form is submitted, all of these copies get called, and they all do a PUT request.

The solution would be to move the form's submit handler out of the way, that is, outside the click handler. That would make sure it's only added once.

Comment: Right! Just as I suspected. At first I thought I wouldn't be able to select the `id` no longer by doing this but I just realised I can declare a variable outside the click and assign it when the modify button is clicked then use it in my submit form! Thank you!! All I needed was fresh eyes on this.

Comment: You're welcome! And you're right, that should work just fine.